# Pyspark Get Latest Values as New Columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My input dataframe is;

```
Date        Client  Score
2020-10-26  1       NULL
2020-10-27  1       NULL
2020-10-28  1       3 
2020-10-29  1       10
2020-10-30  1       NULL
2020-10-31  1       NULL
2020-11-01  1       NULL
2020-11-02  1       NULL
2020-11-03  1       NULL
2020-11-04  1       NULL
2020-11-05  1       NULL
2020-11-06  1       NULL
2020-11-07  1       NULL
2020-11-08  1       NULL
2020-11-09  1       2
2020-10-26  2       NULL
2020-10-27  2       NULL
2020-10-28  2       NULL
2020-10-29  2       NULL
2020-10-30  2       NULL
2020-10-31  2       NULL
2020-11-01  2       NULL
2020-11-02  2       NULL
2020-11-03  2       NULL
2020-11-04  2       NULL
2020-11-05  2       NULL
2020-11-06  2       NULL
2020-11-07  2       NULL
2020-11-08  2       NULL
2020-11-09  2       NULL
```

Input dataframe has score column for each client and each day. For some days this column values is null.

My desired output is;

```
Date        Client  Score   Last_5days  Last_10days Last_15days
2020-10-26  1       NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
2020-10-27  1       NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
2020-10-28  1          3      3         NULL        NULL
2020-10-29  1         10     10            3        NULL
2020-10-30  1       NULL     10            3        NULL
2020-10-31  1       NULL     10            3        NULL
2020-11-01  1       NULL     10            3        NULL
2020-11-02  1       NULL     10            3        NULL
2020-11-03  1       NULL     10            3        NULL
2020-11-04  1       NULL    NULL          10        3
2020-11-05  1       NULL    NULL          10        3
2020-11-06  1       NULL    NULL          10        3
2020-11-07  1       NULL    NULL          10        3
2020-11-08  1       NULL    NULL        NULL        10
2020-11-09  1          2       2        NULL        10
2020-10-26  2       NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
2020-10-27  2         15      15        NULL        NULL
2020-10-28  2       NULL      15        NULL        NULL
2020-10-29  2       NULL      15        NULL        NULL
2020-10-30  2       NULL      15        NULL        NULL
2020-10-31  2       NULL      15        NULL        NULL
2020-11-01  2       NULL    NULL        15          NULL
2020-11-02  2       NULL    NULL        15          NULL
2020-11-03  2       NULL    NULL        15          NULL
2020-11-04  2       NULL    NULL        15          NULL
2020-11-05  2       NULL    NULL        15          NULL
2020-11-06  2       NULL    NULL        15          NULL
2020-11-07  2       NULL    NULL        NULL        15
2020-11-08  2       NULL    NULL        NULL        15
2020-11-09  2       NULL    NULL        NULL        15
```

I want to add some new columns. These are related to client' s latest scores for specified n days(5, 10 or 15.)

I did some research about partitionBy and window, but i couldn' t handle it.

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand the logic, but here's my attempt to get something similar to what you wanted:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('Client').orderBy('Date')
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'last5days',
    F.collect_list('score').over(w.rowsBetween(-5,0))
).withColumn(
    'last10days',
    F.collect_list('score').over(w.rowsBetween(-10,-6))
).withColumn(
    'last15days',
    F.collect_list('score').over(w.rowsBetween(-15,-11))
).withColumn(
    'last15days', 
    F.when(F.size(F.col('last10days')) > 1, F.col('last10days')[0]).otherwise(F.element_at(F.col('last15days'), -1))
).withColumn(
    'last10days', 
    F.when(F.size(F.col('last5days')) > 1, F.col('last5days')[0]).otherwise(F.element_at(F.col('last10days'), -1))
).withColumn(
    'last5days',
    F.element_at(F.col('last5days'), -1)
)
```

```
df2.show(99,0)
+----------+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
|Date      |Client|Score|last5days|last10days|last15days|
+----------+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
|2020-10-26|1     |null |null     |null      |null      |
|2020-10-27|1     |null |null     |null      |null      |
|2020-10-28|1     |3    |3        |null      |null      |
|2020-10-29|1     |10   |10       |3         |null      |
|2020-10-30|1     |null |10       |3         |null      |
|2020-10-31|1     |null |10       |3         |null      |
|2020-11-01|1     |null |10       |3         |null      |
|2020-11-02|1     |null |10       |3         |null      |
|2020-11-03|1     |null |10       |3         |null      |
|2020-11-04|1     |null |null     |10        |3         |
|2020-11-05|1     |null |null     |10        |3         |
|2020-11-06|1     |null |null     |10        |3         |
|2020-11-07|1     |null |null     |10        |3         |
|2020-11-08|1     |null |null     |10        |3         |
|2020-11-09|1     |2    |2        |null      |10        |
|2020-10-26|2     |null |null     |null      |null      |
|2020-10-27|2     |15   |15       |null      |null      |
|2020-10-28|2     |null |15       |null      |null      |
|2020-10-29|2     |null |15       |null      |null      |
|2020-10-30|2     |null |15       |null      |null      |
|2020-10-31|2     |null |15       |null      |null      |
|2020-11-01|2     |null |15       |null      |null      |
|2020-11-02|2     |null |null     |15        |null      |
|2020-11-03|2     |null |null     |15        |null      |
|2020-11-04|2     |null |null     |15        |null      |
|2020-11-05|2     |null |null     |15        |null      |
|2020-11-06|2     |null |null     |15        |null      |
|2020-11-07|2     |null |null     |null      |15        |
|2020-11-08|2     |null |null     |null      |15        |
|2020-11-09|2     |null |null     |null      |15        |
+----------+------+-----+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi mck, yeah it's so similar. One more thing is; if last5days column is updated, the older value should be add to last10days. For example; for the 4th row, last10days should be 3 days.